# Pandas: Dataframe Crosstab Output To Matrix

Tags: pandas, matrix, pivot-table

I have a simple dataframe with two columns and I would like to generate an output table showing the differences between rows as a matrix?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie'],
                    'Total': [31.05590, 32.91925, 36.02484]})
```

| Subject | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | 31.05590 |
| Bravo | 32.91925 |
| Charlie | 36.02484 |

The expected output is basically the differences between rows.

For example:

> Alpha-Charlie = Alpha(Total) - Charlie(Total) -> (31.05590 - 36.02484) = -4.96894  and
>
> Bravo-Alpha   = Bravo(Total) - Alpha(Total)   -> (32.91925 - 31.05590) = 1.86335.

| Subject | Alpha | Bravo | Charlie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 0.00000 | -1.86335 | -4.96894 |
| Bravo | 1.86335 | 0.00000 | -3.10559 |
| Charlie | 4.96894 | 3.10559 | 0.00000 |

So far, I have not made much progress!

```
ct_a = pd.crosstab(df['Subject'], df['Subject'], values=df['Total'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
ct_a.to_csv('data/ct_a.csv', index=True)
```

This code generates the following output:

| Subject | Alpha | Bravo | Charlie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 31.05590 | 0.00000 | 0.00000 |
| Bravo | 0.00000 | 32.91925 | 0.00000 |
| Charlie | 0.00000 | 0.00000 | 36.02484 |

I would welcome any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) :

```
out = (
        df.merge(df, how="cross", suffixes=("", "_c"))
            .assign(Total= lambda x: x["Total"].sub(x["Total_c"]))
            .pipe(lambda d: pd.crosstab(d["Subject"], d["Subject_c"],
                                        values=d["Total"], aggfunc="sum"))
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
            .reset_index()
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   Subject    Alpha    Bravo  Charlie
0    Alpha  0.00000 -1.86335 -4.96894
1    Bravo  1.86335  0.00000 -3.10559
2  Charlie  4.96894  3.10559  0.00000
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for both the prompt follow-up and the benefit of your expertise.